# DynamoDB GSI: All attributes projection vs keys-only with multiple read

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Which is more cost effective? Let's say I've the following table

```
CompanyId [Hash Key]
ItemId [Range]
Last_modified
[...other attributes]
```

I've also created a GSI where `CompanyId` is my **[Hash Key]** and `Last_modified` is my **[Range]** so that I can query based on `Last_modified` date.

For my usage, my GSI is querying from another dimension, i.e. I need all attributes from my GSI query and same amount of query as against the main table.

So ... which is more cost-effective:

1. Set attribute projection to **All**? --> increase in storage cost, but lesser read
2. Set attribute projection to **Keys-only**, and for each key, do another read to the main table to get all attributes? --> lesser storage cost, but more read

Comment: testing each option would be the best way to know that for sure. As it depends not only on infrastructure (dynamoDB) but also on data thmeselves. IMO